# C# Menu Class Access

Tags: c#, wpf, class, menu

i would like to use a menu to control the web browser. But i am not familiar with class access.

xaml code

```
<Menu IsMainMenu="True">
<MenuItem Header="Back"></MenuItem>             
<MenuItem Header="MainMenu">
<MenuItem Header="subItem1" 
x:Name="subItem1" Click="subItem1_Click">
</MenuItem>
</MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Class code

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1(): this(OverlayStyle.WinForms)
    {
    }
    public Window1(OverlayStyle style)
    {
        InitializeComponent();



            WebBrowserOverlayWF wbo = new WebBrowserOverlayWF(_webBrowserPlacementTarget);
            System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser wb = wbo.WebBrowser;
            wb.Navigate(new Uri("http://live.com"));



    }
```

How can i create access the "wb" control from menu item

```
        private void subItem1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Many Thanks

Comment: You can't: its only in scope in the constructor. Move the declaration outside the constructor but still in the class, and keep the assignment inside the constructor. Than youll have access to it.

Comment: Rocky--it is considered impolite to ask a question, have someone put in the trouble to answer it and solve your problem, and then walk away without rewarding the effort. If you dont have plans to continue using SO, fine. But dont neglect those of us who do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't: it's only in scope in the constructor. Move the declaration outside the constructor but still in the class, and keep the assignment inside the constructor. Than youll have access to it.
Try this

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser wb;

    public Window1(): this(OverlayStyle.WinForms)
    {
    }

    public Window1(OverlayStyle style)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        WebBrowserOverlayWF wbo = new WebBrowserOverlayWF(_webBrowserPlacementTarget);
        wb = wbo.WebBrowser;
        wb.Navigate(new Uri("http://live.com"));
    }
}
```

Then inside your event handler or other method, you can use `wb` as you will.

Comment: Thank You !!!
Now i can access wb from private void


But it shows an error, saying that i didn't assign a location, will keep using default value null

Comment: Might be worth another question? Describe the error more fully and where it appears and i might be able to help

Comment: Oh sorry my fault. The problem is solved. You are great !

Comment: @RockyLam if my answer helped, consider upvoting it. If it solved the problem, mark the green check. Always feel free to do both.